# Setting Parameters for Random String from Array: Exception n <= 0

Tags: java, android

Edit: I am trying to pass the values of wG1...wG5, which are in the Main class, to rarityType(), which is expecting five parameters. I want these passed parameters to be used in int[], which defines the weight of the items in the rare[].

Hard-coding the values into the function (line 3) works as intended:

```
public String rarityType() {
    String rare[] = {"Common", "Uncommon", "Rare", "Epic", "Legendary"};
    int[] a = {64, 32, 24, 4, 1};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : a)
        sum += i;
    int s = r.nextInt(sum);
    int prev_value = 0;
    int current_max_value;
    int found_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        current_max_value = prev_value + a[i];
        boolean found = (s >= prev_value && s < current_max_value);
        if (found) {
            found_index = i;
            break;
        }
        prev_value = current_max_value;
    }
```

rarityType() is not instanced in Main, it's value is retrieved via getter:

```
Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
String weaponRarity = weapon.getWeaponRarity();
```

And in the class:

```
private String weaponRarity = rarityType();
```

But I want to be able to modify those values from Main.
.

I am trying to set parameters in Main for a class that returns a weighted random string. When I have the parameters hard coded in the class, it works as expected.

The exception is telling me that the random generator returned null because it was not passed any parameters. I tried to create setters in the class and define them in Main, to no avail. My question is, how can I pass parameters to the function in the class that I instantiate in Main? Thank you for any guidance!
Note: I cannot have a constructor for this class in Main because their are other functions in the class that rely on the returned string from this function.

Main code snippet:

```
    Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
    weapon.wG1 = 1;
    weapon.wG2 = 1;
    weapon.wG3 = 1;
    weapon.wG4 = 1;
    weapon.wG5 = 1000;
```

Class code snippet:

```
public class Weapon {
    public int wG1,wG2,wG3,wG4,wG5;
    private Random r = new Random();
    private String weaponRarity = rarityType(wG1,wG2,wG3,wG4,wG5);

    public String rarityType(int w1, int w2, int w3, int w4, int w5) {
        String rare[] = {"Common", "Uncommon", "Rare", "Epic", "Legendary"};
        int[] a = {w1, w2, w3, w4, w5};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : a)
            sum += i;
        int s = r.nextInt(sum); //line 100
        int prev_value = 0;
        int current_max_value;
        int found_index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            current_max_value = prev_value + a[i];
            boolean found = (s >= prev_value && s < current_max_value);
            if (found) {
                found_index = i;
                break;
            }
            prev_value = current_max_value;
        }

        String selection = "unknown";
        if (found_index != -1) {
            selection = rare[found_index];
        }
        return selection;
    }
```

This version of the code throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0 at 
net.zingrook.mobiloot.Weapon.rarityType(Weapon.java:100)
```

Comment: Okay, so what values are you passing in for `w1`, `w2` etc? And no, the exception *doesn't* tell you that "the random generator returned null" - it tells you that it threw an exception because you passed in an invalid argument.

Comment: If your question is about how to pass arguments into a method, then almost all of the body of the method is irrelevant here. Note that you haven't shown how you call the method - and *that's* where you would pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because rarityType method is executed when you create weapon object but wG1,wG2,wG3,wG4,wG5 are not instantiated yet:

```html
 Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
```

probably it will make sense to create a constructor with all these parameters. Please let me know if you have any questions.